# ANT - How do you change the src.dir property?

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to build an Android project using a local build.xml file. Inside it I have:

```
<property name="src.dir" value="test"/>
```

I run Ant as follows:

```
ant debug
```

I then get an error stating that folder 'src' does not exist. Why is Ant ignoring the src.dir property I am trying to set? I want it to look inside the 'test' folder for my source, not the 'src' folder.

My build.xml is in the same folder than I am executing 'ant debug' from. Here is the error I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:659: /Work/TT/android-TT/app/src/main/src does not exist.
```

And here is my build.xml file which imports a standard Android build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="app" default="help">

    <property name="src.dir" value="test"/>

    <!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
         It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
         Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />

    <!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
         'android' tool to add properties to it.
         This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
         files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
         get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
         This must be done before we load project.properties since
         the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>

    <!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.

         This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
         dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
         (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <!--
        Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
        This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
            -pre-build
            -pre-compile
            -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                           Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                           If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
            -post-package
            -post-build
            -pre-clean
    -->
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

    <!-- Import the actual build file.

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <import> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole content of build.xml
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, replacing the <import> task.
             - customize to your needs.

         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Comment: You have two property files. Are you overriding the "src.dir" property? You can run ANT in debug mode to see all the property values being set.

Comment: what is your directory structure?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Good tip - ant -v debug was very useful for the next problem I encountered. Not sure if verbose mode was what you were referring to or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the property pointing on 'src' folder is `source.dir` which should be defined in the android `build.xml` you are importing at the end of your build file. You may override it by adding a line `source.dir=test` to the file `ant.properties` (as it is mentioned in the comment above the line `<property file="ant.properties" />`).

Comment: Excellent! I created an ant.properties file and now it is trying to use the correct source folder. Answer accepted!